# How do I interpret the output of a fuzzy regression discontinuity with rdd_gen_reg in R's rddtools?

Tags: r, regression, instrumental-variables, regression-discontinuity

I'm running a fuzzy regression discontinuity in R. I'm trying to understand the interpretation of each coefficient in the regression output.
I know that x is the effect of the running variable on the outcome to the left of the cutoff, x+x_right is the effect of the running variable on the outcome to the right of the cutoff, but I don't understand D and ins.

I know they must have to do with the effects of the instrument and the treatment, but I'm not exactly sure how.

My outcome y is binary, so I'm using a probit link function.

My code is this:

```
rdd_data_full = rdd_data(y=y,x=x,
                           cutpoint = cutpoint, z = z)
rdd_full = rdd_gen_reg(rdd_object=rdd_data_full,fun=glm,family=binomial(link='probit'),slope='separate',order=1)
```

And my output is this:

````
Call:
fun(formula = y ~ ., family = ..1, data = dat_step1, weights = weights)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5845  -1.4928   0.8441   0.8807   0.9633  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  0.4827202  0.0152462  31.662   <2e-16 ***
D           -0.1843083  0.0139786 -13.185   <2e-16 ***
x            0.0051875  0.0033124   1.566    0.117    
x_right      0.0003811  0.0037638   0.101    0.919    
ins          0.0184554  0.0196553   0.939    0.348    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 94258  on 75420  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 94076  on 75416  degrees of freedom
AIC: 94086

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```
````

Comment: Can you give minimal data for this?